# C#: is System.Type not a real type? or: working around single dispatch

Tags: c#, polymorphism, type-conversion, multiple-dispatch

I've been trying to work around C# not having polymorphic dispatch based on the method argument type, and I have encountered that you can't pass types around.

I basically have an abstract class `Model` that implements two methods: `IEnumerable<Decision> GetDecisions()` and `void TakeDecision(Decision decision)`. `Decision` is an abstract class as well. The consumer of this class repeatedly gets possible decisions, evaluates them and passes the best one back to the `Model`.

Each single derived model can work with some common decisions and some model-specific decisions and I have a separate `TakeDecision()` method for each `Decision` type this specific `Model` can work with. The problem is of course with single dispatch. Ideally, the consumer would do this:

`var m = ModelFactory.GetModel(some parameters); //m is type Model
var ds = m.GetDecisions(); //ds is IEnumerable<Decision>
//Some logic here to choose the best Decision d
m.TakeDecision(d);`

Now I have to implement logic that looks like this in every derived `Model`, because C# can dispatch to the correct `Model` implementation, but not to the correct overload:

`if (decision is FooDecision) TakeDecision((FooDecision)decision);
if (decision is BarDecision) TakeDecision((BarDecision)decision);
...`

or I force the consumer to do the casting on their side (they have most likely already done it to examine the decision).

I wanted to have a list of `System.Type`s in each derived class, so I could do this:

`foreach (var t in AllowedDecisionTypes) {
    if (decision is t) TakeDecision((t)decision);
}`

but it looks like `System.Type` is not a real type:

1. You can't do this: `AllowedDecisionTypes.Add(FooDecision)`, but you can do `AllowedDecisionTypes((new FooDecision()).GetType())`
2. And vice versa, you can't do `decision is AllowedDecisionTypes[0]`, but you can do `decision is FooDecision`.

Is there a way to have both? I.e., generate a list of types and cast to them? Or is the only way out to do double dispatch and implement `void Decision.ApplyTo(Model model) { model.TakeDecision(this); }`, on each decision, which should probably dispatch to the correct overload, since `this` is now a specific `Decision`?

Answer (score 0):

To add a `Type` to a list of `Type` objects you simply need to use the `typeof` operator instead of just adding the type.

The equivalent operation to `is` for a `Type` objects is to use its `IsAssignableFrom` method.

You won't be able to cast an object based on a `Type`; the way to call one of multiple overloads based on a `Type` is through reflection.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on the proper way to call the right overload without using reflection?

Comment: @Alexey There is no way.  You need to use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

`Type` is an object describing a certain type, but it's not the type itself if we look at it this way: `String != typeof(String)`.

What you can do is this:

```
// Add type to collection of Type
AllowedDecisionTypes.Add(typeof(FooDecision))

// Check if the current decision EXACTLY of the same type
if(myDecision.GetType() == AllowedDecisionTypes[0])

// Check if the current decision inherits/implements that type (like using the 'is' operator)
if(AllowedDecisionTypes[0].IsAssignableFrom(myDecision.GetType()))
```